# SciKit Learn: TypeError: fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y' while initializing constructor properly with ()

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm trying to use SciKit Learn's linear regression to analyze a dataset. My dataset is a csv file with data and a row of labels. My code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from sklearn import linear_model

data = pd.read_csv('temp.csv')

reg = linear_model.LinearRegression()
reg.fit(data)
```

When I run this code, I get the error: `TypeError: fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'`

Other programmers with this error seem to have generally not properly initialized the model (by leaving out the parentheses for the default constructor) however I have the parentheses and I pulled my initialization statement directly from an sklearn example. Thus, I'm not really sure what's wrong.

While I have done a reasonable amount of machine learning model work in the past, I exclusively used TensorFlow. I'm now working with a group that uses SciKit learn, but my low experience with it means that this could be a very simple error that I'm overlooking!

Comment: [`sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.fit()`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.fit) has two required arguments, `X` and `y`. Try something like: `reg.fit(X=data[list_of_feature_columns], y=data[target_variable_column])`

Comment: please provide a sample of your `.csv` file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LinearRegression` is a supervised learning method. So you have to provide `y` labels when trying to fit your model. So in your `temp.csv` file, you should have a column representing `y` values of your dataset.

something like this(if you have one column for y label):

```
data = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')
x = data[:,:-1]
y = data[:,-1]
regressor = linear_model.LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(x,y)
```

Answer (score -1):

The definition of fit is

```
fit(X, y, sample_weight=None)
```

You have supplied X as "data" but you need to supply y parameter value also. Here y is the labels i.e., classes for each data line in your "data".
By calling fit you are training your model which means, you are telling that for each data line y should be the class. Therefore you need to supply y as well else you will get above error